# Android Studio v7- Import errors for few classes (Cannot resolve symbol)

Tags: java, android

I am a beginner to Android Programming. I am trying to create a basic Hello World App using Android Studio. I am getting following errors in Java File immediately after following the initial steps to create the Hello World Program.

```
"Cannot resolve Symbol FloatingActionButton"
"Cannot resolve Symbol Snackbar"
"Cannot resolve Symbol AppCompatActivity"
"Cannot resolve Symbol Toolbar"
```

As you can see in the attached [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02PwS.png) the errors are in red.
Please help me out here.

My build file content:

```
 defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.helloworld.helloworld"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
}
```

Seems like I have added all the relevant dependencies.

Comment: Have you try to restart the Android Studio ?

Comment: Yes, that doesn't help

Comment: I wonder if the solution for this issue was found for the latest AndroidStudio updates (since end of March-2018). Now, the `compile` in `dependencies` is "obsolete", and I tried to add a previous version as the answers suggests, but it didn't work for me

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue after inserting a new module with a blank activity into an existing project.

My module's `build.gradle` file looked like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.networkingtest"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
}
```

To resolve the issue I changed the versions of the appcompat and design dependencies from 23.1.0 to 23.0.1 (Note: this is the same version as in `buildToolsVersion`). Next I hit "Sync project with gradle files" followed by Build > Clean Project. After completion the project would run, but I changed the dependency versions back to 23.1.0, hit "Sync project with gradle files" followed by Build > Clean Project again. Now everything works.

Answer (score 3):

Include `compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'` in `build.gradle(Module:app)`

Change the version `25.3.1` to match your `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'` dependency

Import `import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;` in activity

Answer (score 1):

Did you sync your project?

[image]

Also try deleting all "red" imports and re-import this classes.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue when i created a project with an empty activity and further added a second activity which was of type Blank activity.

The steps which got me out was 
1-Build->Clean Project
2-Sync Project with Gradle Files

Tried it on Android Studio version 1.5.1 with minSDKVersion 17.

Answer (score 1):

add the support:design in build.gradle: module app to dependencies this will fix it

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
```

Answer (score 0):

had the same problem. try to insert

`compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0'
 compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'`

at the end of you buidl.gradle file.